# Binary Search Tree: Remove TreeNode with given value x non recursively using Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, treenode

I am trying to write a non-recursive method that removes a node within a binary search tree if it contains the given input value int x in Java. I figured I need to use a stack but can't seem to figure out how to remove the node without calling the function on itself.

This is my TreeNode class as of now.

```
class TreeNode {

    private int data;             // data item (key)
    private TreeNode left;         // this node's left child
    private TreeNode right;        // this node's right child       

    // The "external node" is a special node that acts as a sentinel.

    private final static TreeNode externalnode = TreeNode.createExternalNode();

    /* Return a TreeNode that represents an "external node"*/
    public static TreeNode getExternalNode() {
            return externalnode;
    }

    /* Creates a new TreeNode with no children.
      */
    public TreeNode(int id) {     // constructor
          data = id;
          left = externalnode;
          right = externalnode;

    }
```

I have tried this but cant get it to work.

```
public TreeNode removeB(int x){
    if (this == externalnode) return externalnode;
    TreeNode one = new TreeNode(this.data);
    System.out.println(this);
    Stack<TreeNode> s = new Stack();       
    s.push(one);
    //System.out.println(s);
    boolean check;
    boolean check1;
    while(check = true){
        if(x == one.left.data){
            System.out.println(one.left.data);
            check = false;
            return one.left;
        }


        if(x == one.right.data){
            System.out.println(one.right.data);
            check1 = false;
            return one.right;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please include what you have tried so far, with respect to `removeNode()`. My suggestion is to first implement the standard recursive solution for that method, which is widely documented, and then to adapt it to an iterative one. The only difference will be during search for the node, where you will use a `while` loop instead of recursing. The code that actually handles parent/child linking logic should be quite similar.

Comment: @Jameson I have updated and added the code

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to first perform a binary search to find the node to remove.  In pseudo-code, it looks something like:

```
while (currentNode != null && currentNode.value != target) {
  if (currentNode.value > target) {
    currentNode = currentNode.left;
  } else if (currentNode.value < target) {
    currentNode = currentNode.right;
  }
}
```

Once you've targeted that node, you replace it with one of its children, and then graft in the other orphaned child under it, just as you would add any node.